# How can I work around a RefCell issue?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct with two C pointers and one Rust `HashMap`.

```
struct MyStruct {
    p1: *mut ...,
    p2: *mut ...,
    hm: Box<HashMap<...>>
}
```

My struct gets handled as an `Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>>` and I have a C function that gets called like this:

```
c_call(my_struct.borrow().p1, my_struct.borrow().p2);
```

C has a Rust callback that gets called during the execution of `c_call` that requires a `my_struct.borrow_mut()`, but `my_struct` is already borrowed for `c_call` which needs `p1` and `p2`, so I get `RefCell<T> already borrowed`.

The problem is that `c_call` can't be changed and it needs immutable access to `p1` and `p2` and some `borrow_mut` of `my_struct`.

Here's an MCVE:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::mem::uninitialized;
use std::os::raw::c_void;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct MyStruct {
    p1: *mut c_void,
    p2: *mut c_void,
    hm: Box<HashMap<String, String>>
}

// c_call can't mutate hm because my_struct is already borrowed
// c_call can't be changed
fn c_call(_p1: *mut c_void, _p2: *mut c_void, my_struct: Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>>) {
    my_struct.borrow_mut().hm.insert("hey".to_string(), "you".to_string());
}

// call only receives Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>> and need to call c_call
fn call(my_struct: Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>>) {
    c_call(my_struct.borrow().p1, my_struct.borrow().p2, my_struct.clone());
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let my_struct = MyStruct {
            p1: uninitialized::<*mut c_void>(), // irrelevant
            p2: uninitialized::<*mut c_void>(),
            hm: Box::new(HashMap::new())
        };

        let my_struct = Rc::new(RefCell::new(my_struct));

        call(my_struct);
    }
}
```

([Playpen](http://is.gd/uxd3Is))

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just copy `p1` and `p2` out of `my_struct`?  They're just weirdly typed integers, after all...

Comment: Then you'd have to move the `RefCell` onto the `hm` field and then `p1` and `p2` can't be modified anymore.

Comment: BTW, the Box around the HashMap is almost certainly pointless, you can just store the HashMap directly.

Comment: @delnan Was thinking about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that calling `borrow()` in the arguments of the `c_call` call will borrow the object until the call finishes. If you change that to

```
let (p1, p2) = {
    let x = my_struct.borrow();
    (x.p1, x.p2)
};
c_call(p1, p2, my_struct.clone());
```

Then the borrow ends before the `c_call` call, so `c_call` can `borrow_mut` your object, too.

Comment: Calling `borrow()` twice is not the issue, but this does work.

Answer (score 2):

Rust handles borrowing different fields of a single `struct` just fine, however in order to see this all fields must be borrowed in the same lexical item (a single function, for example).

You thus have at least two avenues for proceeding:

- refactor your borrows so that you pick the `struct` apart in a single place, getting references to each of its fields
- refactor your borrows so that the first one ends before the second one is needed

Depending on your situation, which solution you pick will differ:

- picking the `struct` apart means being able to pass a reference to the field instead of the whole `struct`
- ending the borrow first means being able to copy the data of the borrowed fields instead of keeping a reference